# Is there a way to suggest changes to a file in GitHub without a pull request?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I'm working on a project in which the number of contributors is small, 2-3 engineers.

I know I can suggest code changes in an existing pull request, but I'm working in a capacity where I've been asked to advise, not code. So it seems a little weird to create a fork/branch of main/master, and create a pull request against the repo in which nothing has changed, and suggest changes via commented code (which would list out the changed files where I want to make suggestions).

I want to suggest changes where I can just highlight the code and a comment box pops up, add my notes, like how it works in a normal pull request.

I know of `gists` but I'm not quite sure that is really what I'm looking for.

**Note** - *I realize what I'm asking for is probably ridiculous because anyone with a github account could suggest a change to a popular repo and leave a comment "THIS SUCKS!" but yeah, this is assuming that the suggestions are limited to accounts associated with the project.*

Comment: Related: https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/284

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a ticket in the team's issue tracker. Be as specific as possible about your suggestion.

If the team isn't using an issue tracker, then they really should start. GitHub has a decent built-in one (called Issues), or you can use an external tracker (Jira is the best-known but there are others), but the important part is keeping track of work that needs to be done (bugs, suggestions, new features, etc.).

Comment: It seems like using Issues is prob my best bet - what I don't really like is it seems I can only highlight one block of code that gets pre-populated into my issue. I'd either have to highlight a huge block of code to cover all the pieces I want to suggest changes to, or copy and paste the reference multiple times, editing the line references for each block. Le sigh. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No, not exactly anyway. In GitHub, the best you can do for that exact situation is to create an issue and add a link to the file and line in the repo you want to discuss in the issue description.

GitHub issues use a pretty standard markdown syntax so if you add a []() (with the  hyperlinked text in square brackets and a link to the code in the parentheses) you can effectively mark those lines.

The link url should look like this:

```
https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/blob/master/<full path to file>#L<line number>
```